# QFileDialog doesn't work with tags in OSX and Qt 5.7

Tags: macos, qt, symlink, qfiledialog

I need `fileDialog` to work properly with tags. On OSX, when I try to click on tag - this code removes all files from file dialog, so I can't pick them.

Looks like I found solution `Option::DontResolveSymlinks` but it doesn't work either.

**Update:** if filter is `"Any (\*.\*)"` it shows folders, in other cases it doesn't. Like it disables files to be chosen - I already came up with workaround, but hope there is a solution.

```
QStringList filenames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(nullptr, 
                                                      caption,
                                                      lastDirPath,
                                                      filter,
                                                      nullptr,
                                                      QFileDialog::Option::DontResolveSymlinks);
```

**Update:** added screen to describe what "tag" is
[image: tag example]

Comment: Why not use filter `"Any (*)"` or `"Any(*.*)"`?

Comment: @rubenvb Don't know, actually. Just wrote it automatically like for other filters *.jpg and etc. But it still change nothing, cause base case is in usage of other filters, not just Any.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what do you mean by "tags" here?

Comment: Could you please tell use exactly what you're trying to achieve? As it stands, I can't make heads nor tails out of your question. Please include screenshots of what you want to achieve, what you get instead, and the exact and complete test case you used to get the incorrect result.

Comment: @rubenvb https://support.apple.com/en-mn/HT202754

Comment: I know what tags are. I still don't know what doesn't work for you. Be exact: show what you expect, what you get, what code you used, why you think it should work differently, and so on. We can't read your mind.

Comment: @KubaOber I expect that folder "Work files" will be shown in file dialog, but it isn't. It works only when filter is "Any (*)". If you want, I can add screenshots, but I think they are redundant in such case.

Comment: Show the exact code you use to show the dialog, then. Not a modified/workaround one. Show what doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124440/discussion-between-htzfun-and-kuba-ober).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a resolve for the mac file open hang, based on the previous answer.

```
QStringList filenames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(nullptr, 
                                                      caption,
                                                      lastDirPath,
                                                      filter,
                                                      nullptr,
                                                      QFileDialog::Option::DontUseNativeDialog)
```

The mac file dialog is not used, it looks more UNIX like, but it now works.